# lodash: compare two objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I want to make this via lodash:

```
first = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 }

second = { three: 3, one: 1 }

_.CustomisEqual(first, second);
// → true

third = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 }

fourth = { three: 4, one: 1 }

_.CustomisEqual(third, fourth);
// → false
```

But usual `_.isEqual` does not support this method of comparison, is there a way to make this comparison via lodash?

Comment: Are you asking how to write a function that works like that? What have you tried? Have you checked the [`isMatch`](https://lodash.com/docs#isMatch) function?

Comment: yea, `isMatch` works for me, thx

Comment: `_.isMatch()` doesn't work when the "second" variable is the first argument and the "first" variable is the second argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function CustomisEqual(objOne, objTwo) {
  return !!_([objOne]).filter(objTwo).size();
}

first = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 }
second = { three: 3, one: 1 }

var resOne = CustomisEqual(first, second);

console.log('resOne ', resOne);
// → true

third = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 }
fourth = { three: 4, one: 1 }

var resTwo = CustomisEqual(third, fourth);

console.log('resTwo ', resTwo);
// → false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially this:

```js
// mock lodash
var _ = {}

// create custom lodash method
_.CustomisEqual = function (a, b) {
  
  // get array of the keys in object
  var aKeys = Object.keys(a) 
  var bKeys = Object.keys(b)
  // get the array of the keys with the smallest length
  var minKey = (aKeys.length > bKeys.length ? bKeys : aKeys)
  // get the obejct with the smallest and greatest length
  var minObj = (aKeys.length > bKeys.length ? b : a)
  var maxObj = (a === minObj ? b : a)
  // get the length from the smallest length array of the keys
  var minLen = Math.min(aKeys.length, bKeys.length)
  
  // iterate through the smallest object
  for (var i = 0; i < minLen; i++) {
    var currentKey = minKey[i]
    // ignore values that are in one but not the other
    if (maxObj[currentKey] !== undefined && 
        // compare defined values of both objects
        maxObj[currentKey] !== minObj[currentKey]) {
      // return false if they don't match
      return false
    }
  }
  
  // otherwise, they do match, so return true
  return true
}

var first = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 }
var second = { three: 3, one: 1 }

console.log(_.CustomisEqual(first, second)) // → true

var third = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 4 }
var fourth = { three: 3, one: 1 }

console.log(_.CustomisEqual(third, fourth)) // → false
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think below solution might be useful.

```js
var first = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 };
var second = { three: 3, one: 1 };
var third = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 };
var fourth = { three: 4, one: 1 };

function customIsEquals(first,second) {
   var ret = true;
   _.forEach(second,function(value, key){
      if(first[key]!==value){
         ret = false;
      }
   });  
   return ret;
}

_.mixin({ 'customIsEquals': customIsEquals });

console.log(_.customIsEquals(first,second));
console.log(_.customIsEquals(third,fourth));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```